# python pptx change entire table font size

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-pptx

I use python 2.7 with python pptx to create a presentation with a slide that contain a table with data.

I need to control the size of the table and text.

I looked for ways to do so, and I found some things about changing a particular cell's font size using the paragraphs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378435/how-to-change-font-size-of-text-within-a-table-created-by-python-pptx) and here [enter link description here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-pptx/jnJTL3Tc3AQ)

But I can't find anything about changing the entire table's text size...

Ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Font size in a table is set on a run-by-run basis. So you might do so as you're adding text, or you could do something like this afterward:

```
from pptx.util import Pt

def iter_cells(table):
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            yield cell

for cell in iter_cells(table):
    for paragraph in cell.text_frame.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            run.font.size = Pt(24)
```

Comment: could you please provide an example for how to change the font size of the table cell when i am adding it so i will be able to accept the answer?

Comment: @captainshai Please add to your question the code you use to add the text and I'll have a look.